# Ionic local storage not persisting on device

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a problem. When I run my app on chrome data is persistent due to the local storage of te web browser. However, when running on the simulator, if I kill the app, data gets wiped. I have read that localstorage it is a non volatile storage primary used for storing simple data. A DB is not needed for my app, local storage is more than enough. Any reason why this is happening?

```
angular.module('ionic.utils', [])

.factory('$localstorage', ['$window', function($window) {
  return {
    set: function(key, value) {
      $window.localStorage[key] = value;
    },
    get: function(key) {
      return $window.localStorage[key];
    },
    setObject: function(key, value) {
      $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
    },
    getObject: function(key) {
      return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || '{}');
    },
    removeItem: function(key){
    $window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
    },
    removeByIndex: function (index) {
    $window.localStorage.removeItem($window.localStorage.key(index));
    },
    getByIndex: function (index) {
    return JSON.parse(($window.localStorage.key(index)));
    },
    clear: function (){
      $window.localStorage.clear();
    }

  }

}]);
```

Comment: can you share your code for the reference.

Comment: I am using this service.

Comment: try $window.localStorage.setItem(key, value).

Comment: I think you did not understood. Local storage is working and is being saved. I can see it from the developer tools of google chrome. All I am asking how can I make this data persistent when running the emulator and closing the app. After all the final product is going go be run on a ios or android

Answer (score 1):

i am working on ionic and used localstorage(simple html local storage function)

```
  window.localStorage['Invite-Code'] = $scope.passCode;
```

above code set the value in local storage.

```
 var val = window.localStorage['Invite-Code'] || false;
```

above code show the value of localstorage value, if exist or not then its return value or false.
here **'Invite-Code' is key**

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. It turns out everytime you want to run the app on the device you have to execute the command ionic build to get all the recent changes.